# Do I have to clean up an element if I replace it with another in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

What happens to the div in this example? Do I have to delete it or clean it up?

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = 'hello world';
div.replaceWith(span);
```

Or is it garbage collected or something?

Comment: What do you mean by `clean up`? Or by this question `Or is it garbage collected or something?` ? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Like for any other object in js, it all depends on *do you keep an reference to it somewhere ?* The DOM itself will have lost its trace, so it would already be clean there, but you've to check that it's also clear on your side.

Comment: Didnt read into `replacewith` but the span might exist twice afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you release your reference to it once you're done, it's garbage collected; there's no explicit "delete" or similar in the DOM.

So at the end of your code, if the `div` variable isn't going out of scope or is being retained by a closure, you'll want to do

```
div = undefined;
```

...to make sure you don't retain a reference to the div. But if it's going out of scope and isn't retained by a closure, that's not necessary.

---

Side note: The DOM's [`replaceWith`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-replacewith) is quite new and support for it may be spotty.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the variable would go out of scope but wasn't sure if all these elements would hang around in some sort of pool or something.